# Laravel - production.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object

Tags: laravel

In Laravel-5.8, I have this code:

```
$yearStatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('created_at')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereIn('leave_status', array(1, 3, 4))->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first()->created_at;
//Get Specific current year from date
$specificYear = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yearStatus)->format('Y');
//Get Current Year
$currentYear = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
$currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

if ($currentYear > $specificYear){
    $currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereIn('leave_status', [1, 3, 4])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
  }else{
    $currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereDate('resumption_date', '<=', $currentDate)->whereIn('leave_status', [1, 3, 4])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
  }
```

Whenever:

```
$yearStatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('created_at')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereIn('leave_status', array(1, 3, 4))->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first()->created_at;
```

is null, I got this error:

> production.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object

and it points at:

```
$yearStatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('created_at')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereIn('leave_status', array(1, 3, 4))->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first()->created_at;
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no records in database with that filter:

```php
$yearStatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('created_at')
  ->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)
  ->whereIn('leave_status', array(1, 3, 4))
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
  ->first();

if (!$yearStatus) {
  dd($yearStatus); // null
}

$yearStatus = $yearStatus->created_at;
```

Try to send same select in database to check that data exists.

first() - return first record of the result, or null if there is no data in result.
You should always check data returned after first() before use it.

Answer (score 0):

you should get the record from the db, then make sure it's not null, the get the fieled's created_at:

```
 $record= HrLeaveRequest::select('created_at')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereIn('leave_status', array(1, 3, 4))
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

if($record!=null)
{

    $record->created_at;
    //Get Specific current year from date
$specificYear = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yearStatus)->format('Y');
//Get Current Year
$currentYear = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
$currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

if ($currentYear > $specificYear){
    $currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereIn('leave_status', [1, 3, 4])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
  }else{
    $currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereDate('resumption_date', '<=', $currentDate)->whereIn('leave_status', [1, 3, 4])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
  }

}
```

**you should manage that when $record is null too ...**

Answer (score 0):

just remove from query **created_at** that after ->first()

```
$yearStatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('created_at')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->whereIn('leave_status', array(1, 3, 4))->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
```